# bold a specific keyword in an array in android studio typescript

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

i have an array of different sentences in a checklist. I am trying to bold the keywords of each sentence. How do i achieve that?
This is my array:

```
checklist = [
{listID: 1, name:"Check Engine Oil in between minimum and maximum level.",ischecked: false},
{listID: 2, name:"Check Brake Fluid is between minimum minimum and maximum level. (if applicable)",ischecked: false},
{listID: 3, name:"Check Clutch Fluid is between minimum minimum and maximum level. (if applicable)",ischecked: false}
];
```

and this is my html:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let list of checklist">
      <ion-label>{{list.listID}}.{{list.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="list.isChecked" (click)="onChange(list)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

i would like to bold keywords like minimum, maximum, Engine Oil etc. Thank you

Comment: You have to split the strings, add an inner `*ngFor` to iterate over the words, and add styles conditionally.

Comment: Make a pipe for it.

Answer (score 0):

As **Aluan Haddad** Said, Below is an example

1.Split name with your keywords and add to new key(`splittedNames`)

```
this.checklist.forEach(x => x.splittedNames = x.name.split(/(Engine Oil|minimum|maximum)/));
```

2.Loop the `splittedNames` and make it bold conditionally using `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngFor="let list of checklist">
    <p>{{list.listID}}
      <span *ngFor="let keyword of list.splittedName">
        <span *ngIf="keyword != 'Engine Oil' && keyword != 'minimum' && keyword != 'maximum'">{{keyword}}</span>
        <b *ngIf="keyword == 'Engine Oil' || keyword == 'minimum' || keyword == 'maximum'">{{keyword}}</b>
      </span>
    </p>
</div>
```